# The Evolutionary significance of Coelom

Tags: evolution

What is the evolutionary significance of coelom formation?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It is expected that you will demonstrate that you have done research on your own before asking questions here — for example you could start with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coelom …. –––––––– For details on how to use this site, please check out the tour: biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then the help pages on how to ask questions on this site: biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks! 